# How to use Dropbox to share files in Finder by right click on Mac OS 10.8?

Tags: macos, dropbox

In Mac OS 10.7, when I right click a file in Dropbox folder, there's a "Dropbox" option which could share files or get the URL of the file. Also there's a "Dropbox" button in Finder's toolbar.

But in 10.8, that feature disappeared.

How can I share files using Dropbox by right clicking in Finder?

Comment: I don't think it deserved a vote down heh.. he's obviously new to stack..

Comment: What feature is missing? Right click on a file to share, or the button in the Finder toolbar? Or are both features missing? What is your Dropbox software version number?

Comment: @ProBackup The issue is answered below (new version needed for ML). Happens with Dropbox on every major OS X update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might help:  https://twitter.com/Dropbox/status/228603324440657921

long story short.  Update dropbox is what they say.

worked for me, so should work for you :)

Comment: that's it, thansk!

Answer (score 2):

Update to the latest Dropbox [1.4.12](https://www.dropbox.com/downloading?os=mac)
This will get it back.